# Is it possible to match facebook's like button language with visitor's language?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Right now the current code is:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

It'll display the like button in english, as stated in `en_US`.

I have a multi language website and I was wondering if people visiting from different countries could see the like button's language matching theirs. Is there a way to unset the language?

**EDIT:** @luschn

```
if ( window.navigator.language == "pt" ) {       
    var userLanguage = 'PT_pt';
}
else {
    var userLanguage = 'en_US'; 
}
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + userLanguage + "/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: No, you can not “unset” the language. But if you know your visitor’s language, you could initialize the SDK with the matching locale.

Comment: I assume you're talking about what @luschn answered below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User the client language when initializing the SDK:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage.language

Careful though, it is a bit different. "en-US" instead of "en_US", for example. And it seems that it can also just be "en". Make sure to have a fallback just in case.

I would get the language code, match it with an array of all your different languages and put the correct one (or a fallback) in a variable:

```
<script>
    var userLanguage = 'en_US';

    //TODO: check client language and match with an array of your languages
    //do nothing if there is no match (use default from above)

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/" + userLanguage + "/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[your-app-id]&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Here is a link for more information on localization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization